# Strange result with patch of \overarc

Tags: macros, errors, patching

Triying to use a patch for `\overarc` from this answer 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409106/54817

I got this result

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{arcs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\over@under@arc}
{\relsize{-10}}{\renewcommand\RSpercentTolerance{5}\relsize{-10}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Huge

$$\overarc{AB}$$

\end{document}
```

Log file:
https://pastebin.com/T5NRMvtb

Comment: The problem is just the same as explained by Ulrike: `arcs` tries larger sizes, but there aren't defined above `\Huge` and the bug reappears.

Comment: Same result without `\Huge` .

Comment: Adding `fix-cm` package ( without the patch)  I got the same thing

Comment: Looks as if you found an example which shows that @egreg patch is needed too ...

Comment: My question is why those dimensions appear before `\overarc` ?

Answer (score 4):

Different approach, based on [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.5\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\frown}{.4\wd0}}{.5\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\test{abcdefghi}
\test{abcdefg}
\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{ab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's for the answer but my question is  on the patch explained in my question why those dimensions appear in front of `\overarc`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arcs} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@gobblethree[3]{}
\patchcmd{\over@under@arc}
 {\@gobbletwo}
 {\@gobblethree}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$$\overarc{AB}$$

\end{document}
```

I also have the same problem. I have tried to add the above code and it works prefectly.

Refer to the link https://xetex.tug.narkive.com/pBGTS2zG/the-arcs-package#post14, it stated out the problem of the package arcs. To update the code in the package arcs, I refer the link [\overarc command from arcs package and xwatermark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409024/overarc-command-from-arcs-package-and-xwatermark) .